# Как избавиться от ошибки в коде для склейки видео по запросу пользователя? moviepy

Tags: python, gif, moviepy

Я совсем новичок, решил поэкспериментировать, поэтому заранее извиняюсь)
В общем, была задача такая:
-в папке лежат 33 gif с анимацией каждой буквы алфавита
-пользователь вводит слово, например, "привет"
-программа склеивает gif в нужном порядке и сохраняет в папке
Вот код:

```
from moviepy.editor import *


def gif_list(usr_inp):
    lst = list(usr_inp.upper())
    gifs = []
    for i in lst:
        gif_path = (f'"./Video2/{i}.gif"')
        print(gif_path)
        gifs.append(VideoFileClip(gif_path))
    return gifs


def make_gif(inp):
    final = concatenate_videoclips(gif_list(inp))
    final.write_gif(f'{inp}.gif')
    return


user_input = input("Введите слово для получения видео: \n")
make_gif(user_input)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
"/Video2/Б.gif": Invalid argument
```

А если использовать

```
lst.append(VideoFileClip("./Video2/Б.gif"))
```

то работает.
Как исправить, чтобы путь к файлу правильно считывался?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете *UNIX-style path* (пути в стиле UNIX).

- Куда ведет `/Video2/Б.gif`? Он обращается по пути `[корень диска] -> папка "Video2" -> файл "Б.gif"`. В Windows этот путь можно представить, например, так: `C:\Video2\Б.gif`
- А в случае с `./Video2/Б.gif` поведение будет немного другим. Здесь компьютер обратится по пути `[папка, в которой находится скрипт] -> папка "Video2" -> файл "Б.gif"`.

Вам походит вариант номер 2.

Comment: `Введите слово для получения видео:   
апр  
"./Video2/А.gif"  
Traceback (most recent call last):  

  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100  
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100  
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100  
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100  
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100  
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100  
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100  
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100  
"./Video2/А.gif": Invalid argument  
`

Comment: у меня, как во втором случае, файлы лежат `[папка, в которой находится скрипт] -> папка "Video2" -> файл "А.gif"`

Answer (score 0):

**РЕШЕНО!**
Заменил

```
gif_path = (f'"./Video2/{i}.gif"')
```

на

```
gif_path = (f'./Video2/{i}.gif')
```

и все заработало! Спасибо!